# Use a variable of the column names to select the column returned from a query. (asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have searched for most of the day and I believe I may just be not able to explain myself to a search engine. Please forgive me on this.
 I have one drop down list I use to get the column names with the code below.

```
MySQLDataSource.ConnectionString = matt.GetConnectionString();
MySQLDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT name FROM sys.syscolumns WHERE (id = 
      (SELECT id    FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE (name = 'tbl_EquipmentStock')))";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "name";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
```

Now, the intention of my work is to use the selected item from this to create the sqldatasource of the next drop down.

```
   protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    funtions matt = new funtions(); // funtions is the class that contains my connection string.
    string frank = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    a_c_instruction.Text = " Data filtered on: ";
    selectedItem.Text = frank;
    string sql = "SELECT " + frank + " FROM tbl_EquipmentStock"; 
    AnotherSqlDataSource.ConnectionString = matt.GetConnectionString();
    AnotherSqlDataSource.SelectCommand = sql;
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = frank;
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = frank;
    DropDownList2.Visible = true;
}
```

However, when I attempt to get this to work, the DropDownList2 doesn't populate. What could i be missing? Thank you for looking at my problem.

Comment: Checking for `IsPostBack` on `Page_Load`? Also, does it not drive you crazy that you call your data source `MySQLDataSource` when working with SQL Server?

Comment: I thought it was ironic honestly. I started this weekend with really fun names of "Enterprise" and "Veeger" but as I went about the weekend, I just needed one point to move it to keep separate it in my mind.

Comment: I was meaning how `MySQL` is an entirely different RDBMS from `SQL Server` and you appear to be using `SQL Server` but calling your variables `MySQL`...my brain wouldn't let me get away with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it works on my machine.  I'm guessing that, in order for this to happen right after the column is selected, you need to make sure that the `AutoPostBack` option on `DropDownList1` is set to `true`.

Comment: You know I thought it was but i will check again.

Comment: I believe it is I had to set it to AutoPostBack I believe to get the selectedItemText or Value returned from the first dropdown listing, so that would populate the variable of second dropdown list select query. But I'm just not seeing anything in the dropdown.  Oh heck, I thinking about it more, the 'tbl_EquipmentStock' is empty so i have no results.  I been standing too close to the trees to see the forest.

Comment: Alright, I went back to the program, and added some data to the table, and I do not have any results in the second dropdown still. So the first statement works, the second is where I am missing something.

Comment: Ugh comment writing rules.  -- I had added some quotes where no quotes should go and although it returned data on the query it was causing a comparator error. and all is good and we can all go home and sleep, unless the clowns will eat you.